# How do I read and remove a number from a string?

Tags: java, string

So for example, I have this string:

`0no1no2yes3yes4yes`

The first 0 here should be removed and used an an index of array. I am doing so by this statement:

```
string = string.replaceFirst(dataLine.substring(0, 1), "");
```

However, when I have say this string:

`10yes11no12yes13yes14no`

My code fails, since I want to process the `10` but my code extracts just the `1`.

So in sort, single digits work fine, but double or triple digits cause `IndexOutOfBound` Error.

Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/uspYp1FK

And here's some sample data: http://pastebin.com/kTQx5WrJ

Here's the output for the sample data:

```
Enter filename: test.txt
Data before cleanUp: {"assignmentID":"2CCYEPLSP75KTVG8PTFALQES19DXRA","workerID":"AGMJL8K9OMU64","start":1359575990087,"end":"","elapsedTime":"","itemIndex":0,"responses":[{"jokeIndex":0,"response":"no"},{"jokeIndex":1,"response":"no"},{"jokeIndex":2,"response":"yes"},{"jokeIndex":3,"response":"yes"},{"jokeIndex":4,"response":"yes"}],"mturk":"yes"},
Data after cleanUp: 0no1no2yes3yes4yes
Data before cleanUp: {"assignmentID":"2118D8J3VE7W013Z4273QCKAGJOYID","workerID":"A2P0GYVEKGM8HF","start":1359576154789,"end":"","elapsedTime":"","itemIndex":3,"responses":[{"jokeIndex":15,"response":"no"},{"jokeIndex":16,"response":"no"},{"jokeIndex":17,"response":"no"},{"jokeIndex":18,"response":"no"},{"jokeIndex":19,"response":"no"}],"mturk":"yes"},
Data after cleanUp: 15no16no17no18no19no
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1907)
    at jokes.main(jokes.java:34)
```

Basically, what the code is supposed to do is strip off the data into strings as shown above, and then read the number, and if it's followed by `yes` increase it's index's value in `dataYes`, or if followed by `no` increase value in `dataNo`. Makes sense?

What can I do? How can I make my code more flexible?

Comment: Did you try with regular expressions? I'm not familiar with java but it seems as if this could be done with a regex.

Comment: Do you need to remove every number in the string?

Comment: I did not really understand what you want. Can you post some sample input and output here? I can't open that link.

Comment: You're not explaining what you want to have happen very clearly.  Try to provide more information about how you want to alter your input.

Comment: @idionmarcii: How do I use the number then after checking using regex?

Comment: Sorry, can you post a before and after comparison? I am deleting my answer.

Comment: Before and after comparison of what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative, more specific attempt: -

```
    String regex = "^(\\d+)(yes|no)";
    String myStr = "10yes11no";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(myStr);

    while (m.find())
    {
        String all = m.group();
        String digits = m.group(1);
        String bool = m.group(2);

        // do not try and combine the next 2 lines ... it doesn't work!
        myStr = myStr.substring(all.length());
        m.reset(myStr);

        System.out.println(String.format("all = %s, digits = %s, bool = %s", all, digits, bool));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

does it work for you?

```
string = string.replaceAll("^\\d+","");
```

Comment: From what I understand, this will remove the all non-digits. But I want to parse the digits as well as the non-digits.

Comment: @user2027425 from what I understand, your understanding was wrong. `^\\d+` means all leading numbers. `^` is line beginning. this code removes all leading numbers.

Comment: I presume this will just remove them ... does the OP not want to get the digits and use them as well?

Comment: @PeterJamieson is correct. I want to use the number! Is there a way I can extract the leading number, and store it in a variable after converting it to `int`?

Answer (score 0):

How about: -

```
String regex = "^\\d+";
String myStr = "10abc11def";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(myStr);

if(m.find())
{
    String digits = m.group();
    myStr = m.replaceFirst("");
}
```

Comment: You could also remove the ^ from the regex if you wanted to re-use the matcher to get subsequent digits.

Comment: Tried this, `p.group()` cannot be found even after importing `util.regex.Pattern` and `util.regex.Matcher`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    System.out.println("10yes11no12yes13yes14no".replaceFirst("^\\d+",""));
```